# Not to show DataRepeater default view if condition is matched

Tags: site.com

I am using a data repeater in site.com and have a condition.

But I have to hide a default view if condition is matched and show if condition doesn't matched.

Is it possible to do so?
I am not able to find a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the condition?

Assuming you want to do something like "hide the data if the value 6 isn't returned":

You can't do this on the server side, but you can do it in the client. You can just javascript that executes on the page load to hide/show the HTML element (usually a DIV) containing the data repeater.

It's probably easier if you use a javascript framework like jquery.

You could then do something like this:

```
$(".target" ).hide();
```